# How to create Chai/Mocha unit tests for a ES6 class React component?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, chai

I'm having trouble creating Chai/Mocha unit tests for an ES6 class. This project is configured correctly to use chai/mocha, ES6, babel, so that's not the issue. (I can run a dummy test where I check if 2 variables are the same). The error only throws when I try to use the ES6 class React component below. I run the test using the command **npm test**. My package.json is configured to run this command when I run **npm test**:

```
mocha --compilers js:babel/register file/path/to/spec --recursive
```

I am getting this error:

*Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the  component*

**The ES6 class React component that looks like (obviously not all of it):**

```
import ...

class Car extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      color: ''
    }
  }

  setColor(color) {
     this.setState({ color : color });
  }

  render() {
    .......
  }
}
```

**The test/spec JS file looks (mostly like):**

```
import ...

let should = chai.should();
describe('Car Test', () => {
  let car;

  beforeEach(() => {
    car = new Car();
  });

  it('should be red', () => {
    car.setColor('red'); // pretty sure THIS is throwing the error
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thought is calling new Car() just call the constructor and not the render method, which means the component does not start mounting (see lifecycle document https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html). So the warning means "Hey, your component did not start mounting, how come you want to setState, it has something wrong".

If you are ok with using TestUtils, you can have something like

```
var car = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
   <Car />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all problem looks like to be more specific to your component, so without posting at least your render method not much can be said.

Otherwise a quick fix would be to check whether your component is mounted or not, like this:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
   this.isUnmounted = true;
}

setColor(color) {
   if (!this.isUnmounted) {
      this.setState({ color : color });
   }
}
```

Other solution can be to use try catch:

```
setColor(color) {
   try {
    this.setState({ color : color });
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```